# conditional nested routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to check segment of particular URL on route and based on value of segment decide it to handle to another route.Somewhat like below:

```
Route::get('{module}/{seg}', function(){
        if (is_numeric((Request::segment(3)) {
            return Route::get('{module}/{seg}',Request::segment(2) . 'Controller@index');
        }else{
            return Route::get('{module}/{seg}',Request::segment(2).'Controller@index' . Request::segment(3));
        }

    });
```

I don't think above code works but can anyone suggest a working code for implementing above logic in laravel?

Comment: What do you mean you don't think the above works? Have you not tried it?

Comment: @BenSwinburne,I did and it threw error.The error may be on above code or some other reason.So,first,before further digging i want to make sure correct method for implementation of logic as stated above in laravel.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding it as an optional parameter, and handle differences in the controller. Given your code, it might look like this, for instance:

```
// route
Route::get('{module}/{seg}/{param?}', 'Controller@index');

// controller
public function index($module, $seg, $param = null)
{
    // for dynamic index methods
    if (is_numeric($param)) {
        $method = 'index' . $param;
        return $this->{$method}();
    }
    // for non-numeric third-segment params, continue here as usual
}
```